# Consolidate list of ranges that overlap

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-2.x, interval

I wanted to implemented an algorithm in Python 2.4 (so the odd construction for the conditional assignment) where given a list of ranges, the function returns another list with all ranges that overlap in the same entry.

I would appreciate other options (more elegant or efficient) than the one I took.

```
ranges = [(1,4),(1,9),(3,7),(10,15),(1,2),(8,17),(16,20),(100,200)]


def remove_overlap(rs):
        rs.sort()
        def process (rs,deviation):
                start = len(rs) - deviation - 1
                if start < 1:
                        return rs
                if rs[start][0] > rs[start-1][1]:
                        return process(rs,deviation+1)
                else:
                        rs[start-1] = ((rs[start][0],rs[start-1][0])[rs[start-1][0] < rs[start][0]],(rs[start][1],rs[start-1][1])[rs[start-1][1] > rs[start][1]])
                        del rs[start]
                        return process(rs,0)
        return process(rs,0)

print remove_overlap(ranges)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, modify or return, don't do both.

Your `process` method returns lists as well as modify them. Either you should construct a new list and return that, or modify the existing list and return nothing.

Your `remove_overlap` function does the same thing. It should either modify the incoming list, or return a new list not both.

You index `[0]` and `[1]` on the tuples a lot to fetch the start and end. That's best avoided because its not easy to tell whats going on.

`rs[start-1] = ((rs[start][0],rs[start-1][0])[rs[start-1][0] < rs[start][0]],(rs[start][1],rs[start-1][1])[rs[start-1][1] > rs[start][1]])`

Ouch! That'd be much better off broken into several lines. You shouldn't need to check which of the starts is lower because sorting the array should mean that the earlier one is always lower. I'd also use the `max` function to select the larger item, (if you don't  have it in your version of python, I'd just define it)

Your loop is backwards, working from the end. That complicates the code and makes it harder to follow. I'd suggest reworking it work from the front.

```
return process(rs,0)
```

You start the checking process over again whenever you merge two ranges. But that's not so great because you'll end up rechecking all the segments over and over again. Since you've already verified them you shouldn't check them again.

Your recursion process can be easily rewritten as a while loop. All you're doing is moving an index forward, and you don't really need recursion.

This is my implementation:

```
def remove_overlap(ranges):
    result = []
    current_start = -1
    current_stop = -1 

    for start, stop in sorted(ranges):
        if start > current_stop:
            # this segment starts after the last segment stops
            # just add a new segment
            result.append( (start, stop) )
            current_start, current_stop = start, stop
        else:
            # segments overlap, replace
            result[-1] = (current_start, stop)
            # current_start already guaranteed to be lower
            current_stop = max(current_stop, stop)

    return result
```

Comment: `remove_overlap([(-1,1)])` → `IndexError: list assignment index out of range`. Maybe start with `float('-inf')` instead of `-1`?

Comment: @GarethRees, that'll work if you need negative ranges. I assumed the ranges were positive as typically negatives ranges are non-sensical (not always).

Answer (score 9):

In addition to Winston Ewert's comments, I'd add:

1. There's no docstring. How are users to know how what this function does and how to call it?
2. This is an ideal function to give a couple of [doctests](http://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) to show how to use it and to test that it works.
3. The name `remove_overlap` could be improved. Remove overlap from what? And remove it how? And anyway, you don't just want to merge *overlapping* ranges (like 1–3 and 2–4), you want to merge *adjacent* ranges too (like 1–2 and 2–3). So I'd use `merge_ranges`.
4. It's simpler and more flexible to implement the function as a generator, rather than repeatedly appending to a list.
5. Winston's implementation doesn't work if any of the ranges are negative.

So I would write:

```
def merge_ranges(ranges):
    """
    Merge overlapping and adjacent ranges and yield the merged ranges
    in order. The argument must be an iterable of pairs (start, stop).

    >>> list(merge_ranges([(5,7), (3,5), (-1,3)]))
    [(-1, 7)]
    >>> list(merge_ranges([(5,6), (3,4), (1,2)]))
    [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
    >>> list(merge_ranges([]))
    []
    """
    ranges = iter(sorted(ranges))
    current_start, current_stop = next(ranges)
    for start, stop in ranges:
        if start > current_stop:
            # Gap between segments: output current segment and start a new one.
            yield current_start, current_stop
            current_start, current_stop = start, stop
        else:
            # Segments adjacent or overlapping: merge.
            current_stop = max(current_stop, stop)
    yield current_start, current_stop
```

#### Update

Winston Ewert notes in comments that it's not exactly obvious how this works in the case when `ranges` is the empty list: in particular, the call `next(ranges)` looks suspicious.

The explanation is that when `ranges` is empty, `next(ranges)` raises the exception `StopIteration`. And that's exactly what we want, because we are writing a generator function and raising `StopIteration` is one of the ways that a generator can signal that it is finished.

This is a common pattern when building one iterator from another: the outer iterator keeps reading elements from the inner iterator, relying on the inner iterator to raise `StopIteration` when it is empty. Several of the recipes in the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) use this pattern, for example [`imap`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.imap) and [`islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

Supposing that you think this is a bit ugly, and you wanted to make the behaviour explicit, what would you write? Well, you'd end up writing something like this:

```
try:
    current_start, current_stop = next(ranges)
except StopIteration:     # ranges is empty
    raise StopIteration   # and so are we
```

I hope you can see now why I didn't write it like that! I prefer to follow the maxim, "[program as if you know the language](http://drj11.wordpress.com/2008/10/02/c-return-and-parentheses/)."

#### Update 2

The idiom of deferring from one generator to another via `next` will no longer work in Python 3.6 (see [PEP 479](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0479/)), so for future compatibility the code needs to read:

```
try:
    current_start, current_stop = next(ranges)
except StopIteration:
    return
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure it'll fail on `ranges = []` due to trying to fetch the next item from an empty list.

Comment: There's already a doctest for that case. (And it passes.) When `ranges` is empty, the call to `next` raises the exception `StopIteration`, which is exactly what we need.

Comment: Oh, subtle. I didn't think of the fact that `StopIteration` would trigger the end of the generator. Honestly, that feels ugly to me, but that may just be taste.

Comment: It's a natural pattern for building one iterator out of another: the outer iterator reads items from the inner iterator, relying on the inner one to raise `StopIteration` when it's empty. Many of the recipes in the [`itertools` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) use this pattern. See for example `imap` and `islice`.

Comment: I reserve my right to still find it ugly. :) Maybe its just a matter of not being used to it, but I don't like the implicit way it handles the case.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is an error in the algorithm. Example:

- ranges = [(1,5), (2,4), (8,9)]

Expected response:

- ranges2 = [(1,5), (8,9)]

Response obtained:

- ranges2 = [(1,4), (8,9)]

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: This post is more suited to be a comment than an answer. Please put it in a comment.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is an error in the algorithm. Example:

- ranges = [(1,5), (2,4), (8,9)]

Expected response:

- ranges2 = [(1,5), (8,9)]

Response obtained:

- ranges2 = [(1,4), (8,9)]

A small change and the error is fixed.

```
def remove_overlap(ranges):
    result = []
    current_start = -1
    current_stop = -1 

    for start, stop in sorted(ranges):
        if start > current_stop:
            # this segment starts after the last segment stops
            # just add a new segment
            current_start, current_stop = start, stop
            result.append( (start, stop) )
        else:
            # segments overlap, replace
            # current_start already guaranteed to be lower
            current_stop = max(current_stop, stop)
            result[-1] = (current_start, current_stop)

    return result
```